# SQL Server group by just close value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
name    value
-------------
nameA   1
nameA   2
nameA   3
nameB   4
nameB   5
nameB   6
nameA   7
nameA   8
```

and need this result:

```
name   startvalue endvalue
--------------------------
nameA       1         3
nameB       4         6
nameA       7         8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve it with a difference of row numbers:

```
select name, min(value), max(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by value) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by value) as seqnum_n
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_n);
```

The difference of row numbers finds adjacent names that are the same.  Why this works is a bit tricky to explain.  But, if you look at the results of the subquery, you'll see how the difference identifies adjacent rows with the same name.